# Mod rewrite virtual host and Zend

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

My Apache config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /T "/var/www/Test"
    <Directory /var/www/Test>   
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    Alias /N "/var/www/NCAA/public"
    <Directory /var/www/NCAA/public>        
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htacess file in `/var/www/NCAA/public`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /N/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I can go to files in localhost/T, but I get **404** for /localhost/N I get this in my apache log:

`[Sun Nov 20 16:32:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/N`,

so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I want 1 domain to be a regular domain with an alias and the other is a Zend app with a mod rewrute for the `index.php`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the NCAA app to be accessed under `http://localhost/N`? Is it acceptable to access it under a different url, like `http://local.ncaa/`?

If so, then a virtual host entry could look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/NCAA/public
    ServerName local.ncaa
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    <Directory /var/www/NCAA/public>        
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the standard ZF `.htaccess` can be used (no rewrite base required):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```